# Solving a compound ratio problem

Tags: ratio

There is food for 800 men in a fortress for 30 days. After 10 days 400 more men join in. How long the food will last while food per man is 2/3 from before.

I listed ratios as following

```
Days    Men            Food
30      800            1   (all food)
x       1200 (+400)    2/3 (since 1/3 of food has been consumed already by 800 men)

30 : x ::   1200 : 800   inversely proportional
            1    : 2/3   directly proportional
 x * 1200 * 1 = 30 * 800 * (2/3)
 x = 13.33
```

I get the answer while the book tells me it is 20.

I can figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Your proportion is incomplete:  you have two-thirds the amount of food you started with after the first ten days, but it is going to be consumed two-thirds as rapidly each day ("2/3 of the food _per man_") from then on.  So you need another factor of 2/3 in your equation.

Comment: @RecklessReckonner I have found out the solution, What should I do now?

Comment: If you're asking what to do with your equation, you have the number of days the remaining food will last ( x ) times 1200 men  equal to  30 days times 800 men times 2/3 of the original amount of food.  But the _rate_ at which it will be consumed _per man_ in those  x  days is 2/3 of the original rate.  So there should be another factor of 2/3 on the _left_ hand side, given the way you set this up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the daily ration starts at R per man. So there must be 24000R initially. After 10 days there is 16000R left. The number of men increases to 1200 or 40R/3 per man. The ration is reduced to 2R/3, so the food will last for 20 days.